# Identify which fragment currently visible

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have used `expandable` `navigation drawer`.

This is activity in which `FrameLayout`. How can I identify which `Fragment` currently visible to user.

In this activity many `imageButton` so diff `fragment` I have to perform different event so `imageButton onclick`  I have identify which fragment currently visible to user.

`

```
        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/navigation_icon"
            android:id="@+id/titleHeaderImageView"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/header"
            android:id="@+id/wallHeader" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnActivityBack"
            android:src="@drawable/prev"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnActivityWrong"
            android:src="@drawable/no"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnActivityRight"
            android:src="@drawable/yes"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnActivityEdit"
            android:src="@drawable/edit"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnActivitySearch"
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnActivityAdd"
            android:src="@drawable/plus"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnActivityNext"
            android:src="@drawable/next"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnActivitySetting"
            android:src="@drawable/setting"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@color/color2"/>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Drawer Content -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color3"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>


    <!-- The navigation menu -->

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/navigationExpandableListView"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"

        android:background="@color/ex_listview_background" >
    </ExpandableListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

To find the current fragment

```
Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
```

This finds the fragment currently added to your FrameLayout (content_frame).
This should be enough, but if you want to check if it's actually visible, use the following:

```
currentFragment.isVisible();
```

Documentation for Fragment.isVisible() -

> Return true if the fragment is currently visible to the user. This
>   means it: (1) has been added, (2) has its view attached to the window,
>   and (3) is not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

For identifying which fragment is visible now, You need to store fragment name in any string variable when you click on ListView item.Each time when you replace fragment you need to store name of that fragment in that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the following:

```
String currentFragmentName;

imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        currentFragmentName = "Current fragment name";

    }
});
```

Doing it, you will get control of which `fragment` is currently visible

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you needn't to get the current fragment.Just add the event handler in the Fragment Class like following:

```
        view.findViewById(R.id.titleHeaderImageView).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

  swith(page){
     case:1
       ....
     case:2
       ....

  }

}
```

page is the page number.In general, you should pass the page number to the  Fragment when you create it.For example, the Fragment class could use it function to create:

```
    int page;
    public static FirstFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
       FirstFragment fragmentFirst = new FirstFragment();
       fragmentFirst.page=page;
       return fragmentFirst;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you show fragment you have to put it tag into backstack like:

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK);       
 ft.add(R.id.primaryLayout, fragment, tag);
 ft.addToBackStack(tag);
 ft.commit();
```

make a method in base activity like below and call it in your fragment in onactivitycreated() method, it will return tag of the fragment and you can use switch case then.

```
public String getActiveFragment() {
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
    return null;
}
String tag = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
return tag;
```